# Get an access token for a bot with Microsoft Teams for use with graph API

Tags: azure, bots, microsoft-teams

You would think this would be simple, but I'm just trying to call this API:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
```

I'm trying to call it with an access token from a bot registered on Azure.

Where/how do I get the access token?

Should I be able to call this API with client credentials?

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API reference that you are trying to call, `Application` permission is not supported which means this API can't be called via OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow.

[image]

As you can see only `Delegated` permission is supported and accounts here must be work or school accounts, so if you want to call this API in your bot code directly, you can try [password flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)  to get an access_token with delegated permission.

If you need more assistance, pls let me know.

Comment: Huh. That's a little too bad. I really just want to make a bot that can interface with the Teams API (send messages to channels / users, mostly) I don't need the whole Bot Framework which adds a lot of complexity in that it supports numerous other platforms or even the SDK. But it looks like Bot Framework API is really the only way to go...?

Comment: I see, maybe you can deploy a Teams bot directly : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to post to a channel, there are some other options altogether:

1. Posting using [webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)
2. If you have a bot already, and it's registered (added) to the Team, you can look into [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging)

They'll both achieve the goal, but it depends on who you want the message to appear to be from (e.g. must it look like it came from the user? from the bot? doesn't matter?)